# Parse error Unexpected token '�' at 1:1 ��{ on flutter app when running firebase deploy

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, deployment, firebase-cli

encounter the below message when trying to firebase deploy from root project

Error: Parse Error in ...\firestore.indexes.json
Unexpected token '�' at 1:1
��{

I have a flutter app, upon which I also have a functions folder. Below is the file position:

1. AppFolder

   - functions

     - .eslintrc.js
     - index.js
     - package.json
     - etc
   - lib

     - files relative to flutter app
   - test

     - test files relative to flutter app
   - web firestore.indexes.json
   - firebase.json
   - etc

I am running on windows 11 in a newly built pc (so maybe sth is missing?), other devs are running on mac, I have changed the EOF sequence to LF on the 3 files of the functions folder, I have also run these two commands inside the functions folder

`npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save`

`npm install -g firebase-tools`

npm version is 8.1.2

node version is v16.13.1

firestore.indexes.json is:

```
{
  "indexes": [
    {
      "collectionGroup": "something1",
      "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
      "fields": [
        {
          "fieldPath": "created",
          "order": "DESCENDING"
        },
        {
          "fieldPath": "something2",
          "order": "DESCENDING"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "collectionGroup": "something3",
      "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
      "fields": [
        {
          "fieldPath": "something4",
          "order": "ASCENDING"
        },
        {
          "fieldPath": "something5",
          "order": "DESCENDING"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "fieldOverrides": []
}
```

.elslint.js is

```
module.exports = {
  "root": true,
  "env": {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  "rules": {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 2020,
  },
};
```

and package.json is

```
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "device-detector-js": "^3.0.0",
    "firebase": "^9.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.0.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.16.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Please keep in mind that in an older pc running windows 10 and I can deploy by changing only to the LF and running the above commands.

Comment: Can you change the `"lint": "eslint ."` line to `"lint": "eslint"` in `package.json` and see if that resolves the issue?

Comment: I already did that, it did not change anything

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just try to make a new text file and copy the content of generated file inside the new one. Then override the new file with `firestore.indexes.json`

Its obvious that the generated json file has some formatting problem.

Comment: This actually solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I can see the file contents have special characters after pulling the contents down via CLI from Firebase, how strange. File starts like this: `��{`. Anyway copying content to a new file worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem and found that it was resolved by changes to the **firebase.json** file:

Seek **"predeploy":**

Delete the code so that the outcome is **"predeploy": []**

After this, run the firebase deploy function again, and everything should be fine.

Thank you to Max for sharing this solution with me : )